# How to sum specific columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find the average specific columns of my csv file which has been read into a Dataframe by pandas. I would like to find the mean for 2018 Jul to 2018 Sep and then display them.

```
Variable | 2018 Jul | 2018 Aug | 2018 Sep | 2018 Oct | 2018 Nov | 2018 Dec |  ....
GDP      | 100      | 200      | 300      | 400      | 500      | 600      | ....
```

I have tried to use this code but end up with 'Nan'

```
vam2['2018 Jul-Sep'] = vam2.iloc[0:1, :2].mean()

vam2
```

I believe that '2018 Jul-Sep' should be 200 after finding the mean.

```
Variable | 2018 Jul | 2018 Aug | 2018 Sep | 2018 Oct | 2018 Nov | 2018 Dec | 2018 Jul-Sep |   ....
GDP      | 100      | 200      | 300      | 400      | 500      | 600      | 200          | ....
```

Comment: Do you want mean or sum? You have tried `sum` but stated `mean` should be xxx. None the less, it is the same logic

Comment: Shouldn't the mean of 100, 200, and 300 be 200?

Comment: yes. 200. I get 200 when i do mean

Comment: sorry, my bad. I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `0:1` should be removed if need mean of all rows and add `axis=1` to `mean`  per rows:

If `Variable` is column:

```
#for convert to numeric
vam2.iloc[:, 1:] = vam2.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
vam2['2018 Jul-Sep'] = vam2.iloc[:, 1:4].mean(axis=1)
print (vam2)
  Variable  2018 Jul  2018 Aug  2018 Sep  2018 Oct  2018 Nov  2018 Dec  \
0      GDP       100       200       300       400       500       600   

   2018 Jul-Sep  
0         200.0
```

If `Variable` is index:

```
vam2 = vam2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
vam2['2018 Jul-Sep'] = vam2.iloc[:, :3].mean(axis=1)
print (vam2)
          2018 Jul  2018 Aug  2018 Sep  2018 Oct  2018 Nov  2018 Dec  \
Variable                                                               
GDP            100       200       300       400       500       600   

          2018 Jul-Sep  
Variable                
GDP              200.0
```

Comment: hi @jezrael, actually I have also tried this method with the axis. However, i get the result of '100,200,300' under my '2018 Jul-Sep' column. Instead of a single value of '600' since it's a sum.

Comment: after typing 'astype(int). I receive this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100'   . My actual values are actually in millions, could that be an issue? like '1,470,891'

Comment: @Grappyzxc - Edited answer with `.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Comment: with the updated answer, i see that all my values have became 'NaN'.

Comment: @Grappyzxc - Do you change `mean(axis=1)` instead `mean()` ?

Comment: yes. I directly copied and pasted it. I did set variables to be the index, so i used the 2nd one. After setting the index, I did `vam2 = vam.iloc[0:1, 484:496]` as I only wanted the first row and the specific columns. Would that happen to affect anything?

Comment: @Grappyzxc - Maybe problem with whitespaces in values? then `vam2 = vam2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` return all `NaN`.

Comment: I tried to retype my figures in my excel sheet and run again. The codes are definitely working. I may have to retype them all. Thank you! The issue is that the number should not be in comma format in excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['2018 Jul-Sep'] = df.iloc[:,1:4].mean(axis=1)
```